# Looking to dynamically set a min width on a html table if the column headers collide

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make this table that I am working on more responsive and visually appealing. I am using react.js. My table component has varying number of columns based on the data, so some tables I am finding it difficult to fit the information on the page without having resorting to horizontal scroll, or possibly things like the headers and the icons in the th's collide with one another. Initially I set a min width for the table so that the headers don't collide but that automatically made the table wider than it had to be causing immediate horizontal scroll.

Got this image from https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/, looking to have the table initially with the squish method (no minimum width, just 100% width), but try to determine what min-width would be needed for the table not to collide on itself with a horizontal scroll. So maybe dynamically set a media query (if that's possible?) or open to other suggestions.

[image]

Here I set a minwidth for the table but even at full screen it goes straight to a horizontal scroll.
[image]

Here I removed the min width made the table 100% width and this would be ideal at full screen but when there are more columns or at smaller viewpoints it causes it to squish up to a point where it's unreadable.
[image]

Here I have a table with even more columns but even at 1461px screen width it starts overflowing. I also need to avoid having to break words in the headers.

[image]

Was hoping to learn to see if

1. There was a way to know at what screen size the column headers will overflow
2. If there is a way to dynamically set a media query to allow a min width at that point for horizontal scroll?

Or if I am just going about this the wrong way if there is a better way to address this? I would like to avoid collapsing columns if possible.

Comment: as you are using react.js did you try to use library like matrial-UI TABEL it already handled all these cases you need

Comment: I looked into material ui's table page, their example just has a arbitrary min width of 650px. I am trying to see if I can determine based on the characters in the column headers when it would get to a point where has the space that it needs and doesn't collide.

Comment: in this case you need to use js to see how long is the text and by using it you set the break points by also using js , so it's a lot of effort i don't recommend doing it